# PayPalConnectionException in PayPalHttpConnection.php line 174:

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

Hey I'm working on Laravel 5.3 and I'm trying to implement the PayPal Api, and I found a tutorial online, so I followed every step but then I got an error and I don't know how to solve it.

This is the code where I get the error:

```
try{
        $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex){
        if(\Config::get('app.debug')){
            echo 'Exception: ' . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true);
            echo $err_data;/*
            echo $ex->getCode();
            echo $ex->getData();*/
            exit;
        } else {
            die('Ups! Algo salio mal');
        }
    }
```

And this is the error:

PayPalConnectionException in PayPalHttpConnection.php line 174:
Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3SH87897C2313620PLCHWOOY/execute.

Any idea?

Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Deal;
use App\Status;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use Paypal;
use Session;

class PaypalController extends Controller
{
    private $_apiContext;

public function __construct()
{
    $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
    $this->_apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
    $this->_apiContext->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    /*$this->_apiContext = Paypal::ApiContext(
        config('services.paypal.client_id'),
        config('services.paypal.secret'));

    $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
        'mode' =>'sandbox',
        'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
    ));*/
}

public function payPremium()
{
    return view('payPremium');
}

public function getCheckout(Request $request)
{
    $payer = Paypal::Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $amount = Paypal::Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD');
    $amount->setTotal($request->input('pay'));

    $transaction = Paypal::Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription('Compra de Plan '.$request->input('type').' Precio por mensualidad '.$request->input('pay'). 'Descripción del plan: '.$request->input('description'));

    $redirectUrls = Paypal::RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(route('getDone'));
    $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(route('getCancel'));

    $payment = Paypal::Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale');
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    try{
        $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex){
        if(\Config::get('app.debug')){
            echo 'Exception: ' . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true);
            echo $err_data;
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            echo $ex->getCode();
            echo $ex->getData();
            exit(1);
        } else {
            die('Ups! Algo salio mal');
        }
    }

    foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url'){
            $redirectUrls = $link->getHref();
            break;
        }
    }

    Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

    if(isset($redirectUrls)){
        return \Redirect::away($redirectUrls);
    }

    return \Redirect::route('payPremium')->with('message', 'Ups! Error desconocido.');

    /*$response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);*/
    /*$redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;*/

    /*$paymentExecution = Paypal::PaymentExecution();
    $id = $request->get('paymentId');
    $token = $request->get('token');
    $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

    $payment = Paypal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

    $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
    $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);
    if ($executePayment->getState() == 'approved') {
        dd($executePayment);
        dd($amount);
        $transactions = new Transaction;
        $transactions->payer = $payer_id;
        $transactions->paymentID = $id;
        $transactions->amount = array_get($amount, 'setTotal');
        $transactions->description = array_get($transaction, 'setDescription');
        $transactions->statuses_id = 10;
        $transactions->save();
    }
    else
    {
        dd('Error en su pago');
        $transactions = new Transaction;
        $transactions->payer = $payer_id;
        $transactions->paymentID = $id;
        $transactions->amount = $amount;
        $transactions->description = $description;
        $transactions->statuses_id = 11;
        $transactions->save();
    }*/

    /*return redirect()->to( $redirectUrl );*/
}

public function getDone(Request $request)
{
    $payment_id = \Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
    \Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');

    $payerId = $request->get('paymentId');
    $token = $request->get('PayerID');

    if(empty($payerId) || empty($token)){
        return \Redirect::route('payPremium')->with('message', 'Hubo un problema al intentar pagar con Paypal');
    }

    $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_apiContext);

    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($request->get('paymentId'));

    $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_apiContext);

    if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
        return \Redirect::route('payPremium')->with('message', 'Compra realizada de forma correcta');
    } else {
        return \Redirect::route('payPremium')->with('message', 'La compra fue cancelada');
    }

    // $paymentExecution = Paypal::PaymentExecution();
    // $id = $request->get('paymentId');
    // $token = $request->get('token');
    // $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

    // $payment = Paypal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

    // $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
    // $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);
    // if ($executePayment->getState() == 'approved') {
    //  /*dd($executePayment);*/
 //        dd($amount);
 //        $transactions = new Transaction;
 //        $transactions->payer = $payer_id;
 //        $transactions->paymentID = $id;
 //        $transactions->amount = $price;
 //        $transactions->description = $description;
 //        $transactions->statuses_id = 10;
 //        $transactions->save();
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //  dd('Error en su pago');
 //        $transactions = new Transaction;
 //        $transactions->payer = $payer_id;
 //        $transactions->paymentID = $id;
 //        $transactions->amount = $amount;
 //        $transactions->description = $description;
 //        $transactions->statuses_id = 11;
 //        $transactions->save();
    // }
}

public function getCancel()
{
    return redirect()->route('payPremium');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You might have a syntax error in your request payload

Comment: Yes please, if you can share

Comment: I'm trying but I don't know why it doesn't let me post it.

Comment: You can Edit your post, and add it there

Comment: I'm looking through your code, everything seems to be correct. It is weird that you are getting 400. If only you sure that configs are correct

Comment: What should I have in my configs?

Comment: $paypal_conf['settings'] => array of correct parameters

Comment: <?php
return array(
 'client_id' => 'myid',
    'secret' => 'mysecret',

    'settings' => array(
     'mode' => 'sandbox',
     'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
     'log.LogEnabled' => true,
     'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
     'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
     ),
 );  
?>

Comment: Really strange, the last thing I can think is your local openSSL version. Have you tried on a server?

Comment: Don't have one!

Comment: I mean I'm using Xampp but I don't have openSSL

Comment: openSSL is extension that PHP is compiled with, it has to have

Comment: Can you please open your php.ini and find there extension=php_openssl.dll? And check if it has semicolon in front of it

Comment: It has semicolon!

Comment: So please remove semicolon, restart Xampp and try again